# Cannot install DeVeDe after installing VLC PPA

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, vlc, dvd

I've updated to vlc 2.0 through ppa and ubuntu told me that it had to make a partial dist upgrade.

So I did it but then i've seen that devede was removed, i think because it was in conflict with some files of vlc. Now I've removed vlc and all its dependencies via synaptic but when i try to reinstall devede, ubuntu says that it cannot install it because it cannot resolve some conflicts.

Now what can I do?

Comment: Try ppa-purge to reset every package in that repository and then completely remove the PPA from your software sources.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide the exact error messages you are receiving when you try to install with `sudo apt-get install devede`

Answer (score 1):

This is how to clean, remove, purge and reinstall DeVeDe

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo-apt-get purge vlc
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f devede
```

Comment: when I try to install devede i receive an error message that says (my translation from italian):                               devede: Depends: mencoder but it's not going to be installed        E: unable to correct problems, there are blocked broken packages

Comment: Have you tried to fix the broken packages? Tried to install mencoder by itself? Tried to install from a .DEB file as in http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html drop to the bottom of the page for the download section.

Comment: yeah i made it! i've removed vlc, and after a ppa-purge everything went ok!

Comment: Enrick91 can you provide the details of the ppa-purge you performed to get this to work?